# How to Refresh Outlook access_token?

Tags: php, outlook, ms-office, exchangewebservices, office365api

Okay so I am getting Error **invalid_token** while creating contacts to Outlook 
I have read a lot of documentation but I couldn't able to resolve the issue

The Answers that I found but not working for me

I tried adding Scope offline_access to the login API. In that **code** value get refreshed and I am passing that refreshed **code** value to **access_token** API But I am getting same **access_token**

Also, I found that we can refresh **access_token** using **refresh_token** but in response, I am not getting any **refresh_token**.

So how would I refresh the **access_token**.

Comment: As a starting point it appears whatever method your using to obtain the token is working to start with if your getting Invalid_token the rest of what you trying is really redundant from that point (eg your not going to be able to refresh a token if it was never valid to start with). So you probably need to post the method your using to obtain the token and you could also use a tool like https://jwt.io/ to validate it and see what Grants etc you have

Answer (score 1):

Ok SO We Have to Pass the Following Parameter while Calling `oauth2/v2.0/authorize` API

```
&scope=
openid 
profile
email 
offline_access  /*----This Is Important For Getting Refresh-Token--*/
contacts.readwrite
```

Then Using Refresh Token You Can Call Below API

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

with Grant Type

```
"grant_type"=>"refresh_token",
```